# Let java program run indefinitely - restart when it crashes

Tags: java, service

I have a java program that should run on a Windows machine. It should run "forever", i.e. when the JVM or the program crashes, it should be restarted. When the computer is restarted it should also be restarted.

I saw advice to wrap the program as a "Windows service", but the tools I found seem to be either costly, complicated or outdated.

Can somebody describe me a straightforward way to achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: In .net you can write services. I would write a simple wrapper Service that starts a JVM with your app. But there are also ready-made configurable wrappers. How do you define "costly"?

Comment: what about not using java at all but C++ or C#?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Actually, I would prefer not to buy anything but have some step-by-step explanation how to take my jar (and its classpath) and run it on windows in the way I described. I thought that I am probably not the first to have this problem, and that somebody has already written something down.

Comment: Yes, plenty of people want to do that. That's why there are plenty of ServiceWrappers for Java.

Comment: So is there a free one you would recommend?

Comment: I consider a ServiceWrapper the most stable. But you could as well put a start-command-line in a batch and have that executed by Windows Task Host ... I cannot really recommend a Wrapper. Too long since I last researched. But there should also be Open-Source (and free for commercial use) Solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Yet Another Java Service Wrapper](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/) is a tool that easily wraps your Java program into a Windows service. Just start the program, note down the PID and enter it into the wrapper. Two things, which are probably universal to services, should be noted:

- For connection to the network, you need to specify an account with the necessary rights.
- Connected network drives are not available.

Answer (score 0):

For the part where you want to start the program after restart you can create a simple batch (.Bat) file and u can put that file in the startup folder.

Also you can use the same file for running the program when it crashes. you can use tasklist command and check if your java program is running and if it is not .just start the program.

Just check our windows batch this is one of the best things you can get everything for doing anything on windows without anything expensive

Comment: You can search for Tasklist batch to get more details . its is a cmd command to get the running applications
[https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb491010.aspx]

Comment: I don't think this is stable and reliable.

Comment: Well if you want a stable solution you should try c# or vbs.